# Check availability of Apartment

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have following tables

1. Bed(bed id, price, is_active, status)
2. Room(room id, price, is_active, status, bed id)
3. Apartment(apartment id, price, is_active, status, apartment id)
4. Booking(booking id, start date, end date, apartment id, room id, bed id)

When a booking is done for an Apartment, then all rooms in Apartment should be available. And all Beds in the Rooms of Apartment should be available.

When booking is done for a room, then all the beds in that room should be available.

I have to do this for mass Update of Booking records. Checking for availability in a for loop is not feasible. As given below

for(Booking bookingObj : AllBookings){

checkAvailability(booking id, bed, room, apartment)

}

Code is to be be written in the trigger.

Comment: This isn't actually a question, you'll need to rephrase it to clearly ask about what you're struggling with, this isn't a site to get free code written.

Answer (score 0):

I was once like you asking people how to write code but this is a bat habit and MUST change. Try to depend on yourself and write some code; then ask others. Start with pseudocode, look at examples - this might help you in the long run.

As per the question, please find some code below. I am not giving you the whole code as I want you to learn!

```
trigger CheckBooking on Booking__c (after update){
    for(Booking__c booking : trigger.new){
    //Check if the booking is updated   
    If(Updated){
        //Grab the booking Id into a string var, example below:
        String bookingId = booking.Id;
        //Grab the room Id into a string var
        //Grab the Apartment Id into a string var
        //Grab the bed Id into a string var
    }
  // Do SOQL to check if the room, Apartment, bed are available 
   /*SOQL goes here*/

   //Check to make sure the availability 
    if(available){
        //do your logic
    }
    else{
        //do your logic
    }
  }        
}
```

Note: Perform this update on a batch size of 1 so this trigger executes for EACH record i.e. Transaction size is 1.

If you want to make the transaction size bigger do the following: 
 1. add the room, apt., bed Ids to a list and then SOQL to check if they are available

These both should work fine. Give it a try. Cheers!